# Deploy Aurelia JSPM and TypeScript to Heroku?

Tags: heroku, web-deployment, aurelia

I'm trying to deploy the Aurelia-typescript skeleton to Heroku and have been struggling. There are lots of random suggestions online and in Heroku about different configuration settings and gulp settings, but Heroku always gives app errors. I'm still banging on it, but if anyone has done this and had a list of the steps they took or a link to a blog that gives a breakdown of the steps, then it would be much appreciated.  :-)

Comment: You're not going to like my answer, but don't host static sites on heroku (https://divshot.com/blog/hosting/dont-host-static-sites-on-heroku/). Aurelia applications are just static websites. If it's a small site, try deploying it to github pages (http://davismj.me/blog/deploy-to-gh-pages/). If it's a larger site, try using an s3 container.

Comment: That's interesting. It's a small site as I'm learning Aurelia, but will be a much larger app over the next few months. I'll check out that link. Thanks.

Comment: You should have posted this as an answer b/c your blog post worked like a charm for me. I added a comment on your blog too. Thanks!

Comment: done, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku is an excellent platform for developing server-side web applications, but not so great at hosting static sites, according to this blog post: http://divshot.com/blog/hosting/dont-host-static-sites-on-heroku.

Aurelia applications are just static websites. If it's a small site, try deploying it to GitHub Pages. If it's a larger site, try using an s3 container. I've written a brief article on how to deploy to GitHub Pages here: http://davismj.me/blog/deploy-to-gh-pages.